# Plotting multiple routes in Google/Bing maps

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps, mashup

Is there any way I can plot multiple directions on Google on Bing Maps? By multiple, I don't mean *A to B to C*, but rather *A to B* **and** *C to D* **and** *E to F* etc.

I am looking to plot all the roadtrips I have taken in my life at a single place. If we can't do the above on Google/Bing, is there an alternative app/mashup where I can do this?

Comment: have u got the solution for you problem? i am looking for the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

With Google Maps, you can save driving directions to a personal map (the feature is called "My Maps").

1. Plot driving directions from **A** to **B**.
2. At the bottom of the directions, click the link to **Save to My Maps**.
3. For the first one, select **Create a new map...** and click the **Save** button.
4. For each additional set of directions, select the map you just created.

In your map, you can change the color of the lines and markers, delete markers, rename the map, add other points of interest, &c.

[Check out this page](http://maps.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=62843) for more information about "My Maps".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do that natively, however there are some workarounds. This is the neatest thing I have seen so far. http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/multiple-routes-in-virtual-earth/

I used this approach when I had to display around 25 routes each containing around 10 push pings. However, the UI become really sluggish as you approach more than 200 pushpins with around 20 routes.

If you are aware of any better approaches then please let me know. I might have to do some upgrade shortly.